# AAD B2C E-mail verification flow

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am integrating AAD B2C with my application and when it sends an e-mail verification it has a subject title Microsoft on behalf of "example".

How do I change the "example" name to my organization name in the Azure AAD B2C UI?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to change it through Azure Active Directory -> Properties (Name field): https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/ActiveDirectoryMenuBlade/Properties.

At least that is used for regular Azure AD invitation emails.